# Cannot format real number in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, formatting

How to format this in Oracle

```
select TRIM(rtrim(to_char(10.00, '999990.9999999' ),'9999999999999990' ||
                          rpad('.',
                               8 + 1,
                               '0'))) from dual;
```

Output should be 10

Comment: Since your question contains all literal values it is hard to answer sensibly - My answer would be `select to_char(10.00) from dual;` but I don't suppose that's what you want!

Comment: Your solution removes all trailing periods (`.`), `0`s and `9`s from the formatted number `10.000000`, leaving `1`

Comment: @TonyAndrews : yeah.. I was thinking something else altogether  ..:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to remove the trailing zeroes up to the decimal point (and the decimal point if there are no other trailing digits) but ensure that you always have an integer digit (so `0.06` is not formatted as `.06`).

Your query:

```
select TRIM(
         rtrim(
           to_char( 10.00, '999990.9999999' ),
           '9999999999999990' || rpad( '.', 8 + 1, '0' )
         )
       )
from dual;
```

Can be simplified since `rpad( '.', 8 + 1, '0' )` is `.00000000` and:

> [`RTRIM( char, set )`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions148.htm#SQLRF06104) removes from the right end of `char` all of the characters that appear in `set`.

So `RTRIM( ' 10.0000000', '9999999999999990.00000000' )` is the same as `RTRIM( ' 10.0000000', '90.' )` and will remove all `9`, `0` and `.` characters from the right of the string. This is not what you want as it will remove the decimal part and continue into the integer part.

`TRIM` will remove the leading and trailing spaces - you don't need this if you do not generate any spaces in the first place and this is what the `FM` format model is for.

So you can use `RTRIM( TO_CHAR( value, 'FM999990D9999999' ), '.' )` like this:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/57561/3)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE data ( value ) AS
  SELECT 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 10.00 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 10.01 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 0.00 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 0.06 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select value,
       TO_CHAR( value ),
       RTRIM( TO_CHAR( value, 'FM999990D9999999' ), '.' )
from   data
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/57561/3/0)**:

```
| VALUE | TO_CHAR(VALUE) | RTRIM(TO_CHAR(VALUE,'FM999990D9999999'),'.') |
|-------|----------------|----------------------------------------------|
|    10 |             10 |                                           10 |
|    10 |             10 |                                           10 |
| 10.01 |          10.01 |                                        10.01 |
|     0 |              0 |                                            0 |
|  0.06 |            .06 |                                         0.06 |
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want "10", the use `trunc()` or `floor()`:

```
select floor(10.00)
```

There is no need to convert to a string and back to a number.  If you want this value as a string, you can simply do:

```
select to_char(floor(10.00))
```

Comment: `floor(10.00)` is identical to `10.00`

Comment: try this too: `select floor(10.00), trunc(10.00), 10.00 
from dual;` :-)